# Get list of products/offers by category id from Allegro.pl by API

Tags: rest, allegro, allegro-pl

I have trouble with getting list of products (offers) from allegro API by category's ID.

I get token and connect after with Bearer connect.

```
'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
```

Get categories and their IDs.

After that I call https://api.allegro.pl/offers/listing

```
$response   = $client->request( 'GET', 'https://api.allegro.pl/offers/listing', [
                    'headers' => [
                        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token,
                        'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.allegro.public.v1+json'
                    ],
                ] );
```

But I have this error:

> Exception: Client error: `GET [https://api.allegro.pl/offers/listing`](https://api.allegro.pl/offers/listing%60) resulted in a `403 Forbidden\` response: {"errors":[{"code":"VerificationRequired","message":"Access is denied. Verification is required.","details":null,"path": (truncated...)

Can anybody help with it?

Answer (score 0):

From the 15th of March 2021 you need to have a verified application to be able to use that resource. You can read more here: https://github.com/allegro/allegro-api/issues/4213